SFMC SQL string to pull day and month from GETDATE() and compare to day and month from custom Salesforce date field
I'm attempting to create a SFMC data extension using SQL which pulls contacts who's date of birth is equal to today's date. This is so that I can create a birthday journey.
I've been trying a few different strings, but haven't had much luck. The contacts records are not pulling through to my data extension accordingly. I can't seem to get the string right.
My last attempt was per the below:
FORMAT (GETDATE(), 'dd-mm') = FORMAT (Date_of_Birth__c, 'dd-mm')
Any feedback is appreciated.

There are countless examples out there, which are easily found through Google. However most of them don’t observe leap years. This will result in everyone having birthday on the 29th of February only receiving greetings once every four years. It can be avoided using below query:
SELECT
   SubscriberKey,
   Date_of_Birth__c,
   Email,
   FirstName,
   LastName
FROM
   Data_Extension
WHERE
(
       (
               DAY(Date_of_Birth__c) = DAY(GETDATE())
           AND
               MONTH(Date_of_Birth__c) = MONTH(GETDATE())
       )
   OR
       (
               (
                   CASE
                       WHEN DATEPART(year, GETDATE()) % 4 <> 0 THEN 0
                   ELSE
                       CASE
                           WHEN DATEPART(year, GETDATE()) % 100 = 0 THEN
                               CASE
                                   WHEN DATEPART(year, GETDATE()) % 400 = 0 THEN 1
                                   ELSE 0
                               END
                           ELSE 1
                      END
                   END
               ) = 0
           AND
               DAY(GETDATE()) = 28
           AND
               DAY(Date_of_Birth__c) = 29
           AND
               MONTH(GETDATE()) = 2
           AND
              MONTH(Date_of_Birth__c) = 2
       )

)


Thank you Lukas, that solved my issue and the correct contacts are now pulling into my data extension.
